# how return array from function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hello i'm trying to return array from my function but i got this in result:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1be6f5c3
```

but function output correctly, for example:

```
12, 54, 65
```

```
fun main() {
    val array = arrayOf(loopForNumbers(n))
    println(array)
}
```

```
fun loopForNumbers(n: Int): String {
    val array = IntArray(n)
    var i = 0
    while (i < n) {
        println("Input number № ${i + 1}")
        array[i] = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: continue
        i++
    }
    println(array.joinToString())
    return array.joinToString()
}
```

Comment: All this is of course one more reason to prefer lists instead of arrays…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got confused I think, it's better to return the array as-is and then format it

```
fun main() {
    val array = loopForNumbers(n)
    println(array.joinToString())
}

fun loopForNumbers(n: Int): IntArray {
    val array = IntArray(n)
    var i = 0
    while (i < n) {
        println("Введите число № ${i + 1}")
        array[i] = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: continue
        i++
    }
    println(array.joinToString())
    return array
}
```

Comment: Thx, but in that way i got this:
`[I@1be6f5c3`
but if correct it to

`fun main() {`
`    val array = arrayOf(loopForNumbers(n))`
`    println(array.joinToString())`
`}`
`fun loopForNumbers(n: Int): String {`
`    return array.joinToString()`
`}`

it works as it should

Comment: @ispite `arrayOf()` doesn't work this way, it's supposed to take a `vararg` parameter, meaning that it will create one element in the array for each parameter you pass. Here, you're passing a single parameter, so you're effectively creating an array of a single element, which is the string representation of the initial array. While this might print what you expect, it is conceptually quite different, and not usable in other pieces of the code. The code in this answer is much better, because it actually uses the actual array.

Answer (score 1):

> but function output correctly, for example:
>
> ```
> 12, 54, 65
> ```

```
val array = arrayOf(loopForNumbers(n))
```

This creates a single-element array containing (in this case) the string `"12, 54, 65"`.

```
println(array)
```

`println` calls `toString()` on its argument, and for an array `toString` is pretty useless because it doesn't include the array *contents*; `[Ljava.lang.String;@1be6f5c3` is a `String` array and `[I@1be6f5c3` is an `Int` array, but the part after `@` just lets you see if two arrays are the same. Instead try

```
println(array.joinToString())
```

see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html for documentation and optional parameters.